# How to uninstall jre1.6.0_16 in Oracle enterprise linux 4

Tags: linux

I have to install jre1.5.0_10 but jre1.6.0_16 is already installed.

How can i remove jre1.6.0_16.
The application i am try to access requires jre1.5.0_10.

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about removing the 1.6 version. It may be needed for something else.

You can retrieve legacy version of Java 1.5 from:

http://java.sun.com/products/archive/

Get the self-extracting file rather than the RPM version.

Extract it to somewhere like `/opt/java`

Now you have something like `/opt/java/sun_jre_1.5_10`, set your `JAVA_HOME` to that and run the your app from `/opt/java/sun_jre_1.5_10/bin/java -jar <appname>` or set your path to get the java from here rather than /usr/bin/java.

I'd also recommend that you try your app with the latest 1.5 release which is 21. Note that 1.5 went End of Service Life (EOSL) in October 2009 unless you have extended support.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to remove jre1.6, you can install jre1.5 additionally and set `JAVA_HOME` for your application to the path of your jre1.5 installation.

Comment: How it is rpm.bin package

Answer (score 0):

Thank You
I found some thing on java.com while doing some RND.
I removed the RPM package using following steps

Uninstalling RPM packages

a.  RPM uninstallation

Note: If you have RPM on your Linux box, you should first find out if Java is already installed using RPM. If Java is not installed using RPM, you should skip reading. 
1.  Open Terminal Window
2.  Login as the super user
3.  Try to find jre package by typing: rpm -qa
4.  If RPM reports a package similar to jre--fcs, then Java is installed with RPM.

Note: Normally, you do not need to uninstall Java with RPM, because RPM is able to uninstall the old version of Java when installing a new version! You may skip reading, unless you want to remove Java permanently. 
5.  To uninstall Java, type: rpm -e jre--fcs

I have successfully uninstall the jre1.6.0_16.

Thank You for all your help.